# How can this method return an Observable that can be subscribed by the caller method?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, rxjs, firebase-storage

I am not so into Angular and RxJS and I am going crazy trying to subscribe an Observable.

This is my code:

```js
createUser(user, file) {
  console.log(user);

  if (user.password != user.password_confirmation) {
    let passwordError: any = new Object();
    passwordError["message"] = "Inserted password and inserted password confirmation are different";
    this.eventAuthError.next(passwordError);
  }
  else {
    this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
      .then(userCredential => {

        console.log("INTO THEN !!!")
        this.newUser = user;
        console.log(userCredential);
        userCredential.user.updateProfile({
          displayName: user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName
        });

        console.log("PROFILE UPDATED !!!");

        this.uploadFileIntoFirebaseStore(file);
      })
  }
}

uploadFileIntoFirebaseStore(fileToBeUploaded) {
  var n = Date.now();
  const filePath = `user_avatar/${n}`;
  const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);

  return this.storage.upload(`user_avatar/${n}`, fileToBeUploaded)
    .snapshotChanges().subscribe(refStatus => {
      console.log("FILE REF: ",
        fileRef.getDownloadURL().subscribe(urlStr => console.log("URL STR:", urlStr)));

      return fileRef.getDownloadURL();
    })
}
```

As you can see the **createUSer()** method is my entry point to create a new user on Firebase (basically I have to create a user via e-mail and password, save an image file (that came from my custom user registration form page) into Firebase Storage and then create a new object into FireStore (but this is not implemented at the moment in this code).

As you can see at the end of my **createUser()** method I am executing my **uploadFileIntoFirebaseStore()** method by:

```
this.uploadFileIntoFirebaseStore(file);
```

This works fine and correctly insert the file into Firebase Storage.

And here happens a thing that I can't understand.

How you can see into this method I am simply subscribing the **snapshotChanges()** result applied on the storage upload that will "triggered" when my file upload is completed. Into this subscribe I am returning **fileRef.getDownloadURL()** that is an **Obaservable** that I can use to retrieve the URL of the uploaded file when the upload is completed.

Ok now I have to retrieve this value (the URL of the uploaded file) into the previous **createUser()** method (that called this **uploadFileIntoFirebaseStore()** method) so I tried to change this:

```
this.uploadFileIntoFirebaseStore(file);
```

with this:

```
this.uploadFileIntoFirebaseStore(file).subscribe( bla => console.log("DO SOMETHING"));
```

And here I have a problem: I can't subscribe this method. I think because I am returning the Observable into an inner arrow function but my method is returning nothing.

How can I fix this situation in such a way that the **uploadFileIntoFirebaseStore()** return an Observable that can be subscrived into **createUser()** method?

Or am I missing the point and my reasoning is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`.subscribe` is a method of `Observable`.

```js
this.storage.upload(`user_avatar/${n}`, fileToBeUploaded).snapshotChanges()
```

The above returns `Observable` so you were able to `subscribe`.

But:

```js
this.storage.upload(`user_avatar/${n}`, fileToBeUploaded).snapshotChanges().subscribe()
```

The above returns `Subscription`, not an `Observable` so you cannot subscribe.

A Subscription is an object that represents a disposable resource, usually the execution of an Observable.

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subscription

**Solution**

You can use `.pipe` and `switchMap` operator to manipulate the result from the `Observable` object of `snapshotchanges`.

```js
return this.storage.upload(`user_avatar/${n}`, fileToBeUploaded)
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
        switchMap(refStatus => fileRef.getDownloadURL())
    );
```

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap